# Can users change hashed password using md5 after entering a system with login

Tags: java, md5

I have a very curious question wen it comes to md5 hashing, see I have this mock security system (yes md5 is not completely secure) in which when the user logs in using the correct pin I want there to be an option for the user to change the pin while in except there seems to be a complication while doing this. The first is that you get md5 hashes from doing this:

```
echo -n 6357 | md5sum
```

Once using this you take that hash and replace it in this line:

```
private static final String VALID_MD5 = "DF3AEBC649F9E3B674EEB790A4DA224E";
```

This is where things get complicate because I would need a variable in multiple places to replace the hash and the actual number 6357. I would need to have code in this section:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    if( Login.login() )
    {

    }
}
```

That would when a user is logged in it allows a variable to be entered for the 6357 so they can enter any pin they want and it would then return a result once entered. However then once that is returned it would be a different hash so then I cannot keep that hash in the String and it also would have to be a variable equaling the new hash. Now here is the issue if I do this there is no initial hash and the first time there is no passcode and whatever you enter first becomes the passcode and once the program is shut off it will not remember it. So I essentially can't remove the hash to a variable like that without removing any initial passcode completely can I? Is it even possible to allow the user to change the pin in such a setup?

Full code for reference:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pin
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    if( Login.login() )
    {

    }
}
}

class Login
{

private static final Scanner ONE = new Scanner( System.in );
private static final String VALID_MD5 = "DF3AEBC649F9E3B674EEB790A4DA224E"; 
public static boolean login()
{
    System.out.print( "Enter pin: " );
    String pin = ONE.nextLine();
    if( isValid( pin ) && VALID_MD5.equals( md5HexString( pin ) ) )
    {
        System.out.println( "Login successful." );
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println( "Login failed, invalid pin." );
    return false;
}
private static boolean isValid( String s )
{
    return s.matches( "\\d{4}" );  
}
private static String md5HexString( String s )
{
    return toHexString( md5( s ) );
}
private static byte[] md5( String s )
{
    try
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
        byte[] buf = s.getBytes();
        md.update( buf, 0, buf.length );
        return md.digest();
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        return new byte[16];
    }
}

private static String toHexString( byte[] byteArray )
{
    final String HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF"; 

    byte[] result = new byte[byteArray.length << 1];
    int len = byteArray.length;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ )
    {
        byte b = byteArray[i];
        int lo4 = b & 0x0F;
        int hi4 = ( b & 0xF0 ) >> 4;


        result[i * 2] = (byte)HEX_CHARS.charAt( hi4 );
        result[i * 2 + 1] = (byte)HEX_CHARS.charAt( lo4 );
    }
    return new String( result );
}
}
```

Comment: Don't want to be rude but md5 is completely not secure, especially without salt.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can't you just change `VALID_MD5` to a variable (i.e. take out `final`), and just assign the new hash value to it whenever the user changes the pin?

Comment: @Michu93 I did mention that I know it is not secure(mentioned above), for me right now it is the simplest to understand before I move onto something better

Comment: @jingx I know I could do that which I mentioned but what I don't get is if I remove it then what is setting up the initial password? It would require the user to create an initial pin upon startup

Comment: Can't you save this value into database and let user change it after logged in? I don't know if I get it right but do you want to change code program from program?

Comment: What's preventing you from assigning the initial hash to the variable as the, well, initial value?

Comment: @jingx that is where I am confused doesn't that initial hash need to be the variable that can be changed. If I replace that hash with a variable that variable is now whatever the user enters. If it whatever the user enters there is no initial password? Maybe I am confusing myself with this and overthinking it.

Comment: Probably we don't understand problem but @jingx suggested to make a new variable `String newPin;` and assign md5 of new pin to `newPin`.

Comment: @Michu93 ah ok never mind, solved. I was confusing myself and my question is hard to word, I was trying to replace the initial hash and no initial hash means no initial password.